# Check if a number has a comma

Tags: php, numbers

I'm creating a game in PHP and I want to give a user something if they reach each 50 points (50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, ..)

The idea:

If a user has 50 points, they will get money in the game (in a MySQL query).

I do:

```
$iUserPoints = 50 / 50;
```

If the result is "1", add a query.

If they have 412 points, the result will be (412 / 50 = 8,24). So they get nothing.

How can I check that?

Comment: It'd help to know which programming language you're using.

Comment: Also, the question is rather hard to follow. First you talk about reaching 50 points, then 450 points, and then the example is about 412 points.

Comment: It kinda sorta sounds like OP is trying to check whether or not the result of (x/50) is a float or integer. I'd just do a modulus in that case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Modulu to see if a number is divisible by 50 or any other number of your choice.

e.g in C# you would write:

```
if ( number % 50 == 0) 
    { Do Something...}
```

for PHP

```
if ($counter % 50) {
echo "This number is not divisible by 50.";
} else {
echo "This number is divisible by 50.";
}
```